# WCF passing own instance BehaviorExtensionElement

Tags: wcf, validation, interface, callback, schema

I'm making schema validation with WCF and want pass a callback interface (actually the same  IDispatchMessageInspector) to the class implementing BehaviorExtensionElement.

I would like to separate the behaviour "receive a message" from "validate the message" (and logging). I'm able to add a class implementing BehaviorExtensionElement. Also I'm able to pass string parameters to this instance. I would like to define an instance (implementing IDispatchMessageInspector) in Web.config and pass this instance to the concrete class implementing BehaviorExtensionElement.

How is this best achieved?

Thanks. Nikolaj